# Update Textview text multiple times in one function using Swift

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextview

I've been writing a simple program using Xcode in which a cipher is randomly generated and used to encode strings. Occasionally a string would take a exceptionally long time to generate. So I figured I'd have the text view display the encoded string as it was generated, to show the user the program was working.

```
<!-- language: swift -->
@IBOutlet weak var textViewer: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var generate: UIButton!
@INOutlet weak var inputText: UITextField

var codeType = true

func Encode(text: String) -> String {
    // lots of string manipulation
    for foo { // A for loop iterating through every char of text
        code += secretMessage[foo]
        textViewer.text = code
    }
    return code
}

@IBAction func GenerateCode(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var message = "Well Something Went Wrong"
    if self.codeType = true { // Check if user is encoding or decoding
       message = Encode(text: inputText.text!)
    }
    textViewer.text = message
}
```

But the text field would only ever update after the function finished generating the code. How do I make text field update character by character instead of all at once

Comment: Unrelated but please note that standard naming conventions state that variable and method names should start with lowercase letters while class names start with uppercase letters. This will make you code easier to read.

Comment: Have you tried to dispatch on the main queue to make sure it updates on the correct thread?

Comment: @rmaddy That makes sense, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to dispatch the text update on the main queue for the visual state of the textfield. One of the key indicators is an error message in the console. Something along the lines of "Attempted to update visual layout " Should have something like the following to try and fix the issue

```
func encode(text: String) -> String {
    // lots of string manipulation
    for foo { // A for loop iterating through every char of text
        code += secretMessage[foo]
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.textViewer.text = code
        }
    }
    return code
}

@IBAction func GenerateCode(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var message = "Well Something Went Wrong"
    if self.codeType = true { // Check if user is encoding or decoding
       DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
           message = Encode(text: inputText.text!)
       }
    }
    // textViewer.text = message // Shouldn't need this line anymore
}
```

Comment: That's the correct approach... but `encode` function has to be executed asynchronously on a background thread. Right now, the code is blocking the main thread.

Comment: I hadn't even thought of that but now that you mention it that makes perfect sense.

Comment: I have updated the answer to fire encode from a background thread. You might need to move the background thread into your encode function but this should get you going at least.

Comment: @BinaryPlatypus When I was originally searching for an answer to the problem I found something about dispatch queue and attempted to use them an have it run in the background, but I was unable get the function to return correctly. I will try your solution and see if it works

Comment: @BinaryPlatypus I tried your solution and the function was never called. Could you explain what you mean by move the encode function into the background.

Comment: @BinaryPlatypus I messed around with which line of code was main or background and eventually figured out it out. Thanks